# Is a notify signalled on thread finish? Why does this code sample work?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, wait, notify

I am looking in some puzzles for threads and I can't figure out why the following consistently prints `999999`:

```
class Job extends Thread {  
    private Integer number = 0;  
    public void run() {  
        for (int i = 1; i < 1000000; i++) {  
            number++;  
        }  
    }  
    public Integer getNumber() {  
        return number;  
    }  
}  
public class Test {  
    public static void main(String[] args)   
    throws InterruptedException {  
        Job thread = new Job();  
        thread.start(); 
        synchronized (thread) {  
            thread.wait();  
        }  
        System.out.println(thread.getNumber());  
    }  
}
```

There is no `notify` on the same lock (and spurious wakeup seem to be ignored).
If a thread finishes does a notify get signalled or something?
How come `main` prints the result and not get "stuck" waiting?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In the Javadoc for Java 7 [Thread.join(long)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#join%28long%29)

> This implementation uses a loop of this.wait calls conditioned on this.isAlive. As a thread terminates the this.notifyAll method is invoked. It is recommended that applications not use wait, notify, or notifyAll on Thread instances.

Using a Thread directly this way is considered bad practical.  Note: wait() could end for any number of reasons, possibly spuriously.

---

Based on a puzzler related to @Voo's comment. The point is you shouldn't play with the internal behaviour of Thread as this is more likely to lead to confusion.

```
public static String getName() {
    return "MyProgram";
}
public static void main(String... args) {
    new Thread() {
       public void run() {
           System.out.println("My program is " + getName());
        }
    }.start();
}
```

What does this program print?

Comment: Interesting... that's been added recently, it's not in my Java 6 source

Comment: Added a note this is from Java 7. AFAIK, all the previous versions did this.

Comment: Yep that was already a puzzle in Java puzzlers so it's at least been there since Java5. Really just never make an anonymous thread and avoid these problems.

Comment: @Voo added a puzzler on this topic. ;)

Comment: @PeterLawrey: I don't think _that_ puzzle helps regarding the question. The question is not about ambiguous method names but about who calls `notifyAll` in a secret way.

Comment: @Peter That wasn't the one I was thinking of (but the one where you acquire a lock on this, then join() and realize you lost the lock), but that one's fun too - if not more so. Yeah subclassing thread is broken in so many ways it's not even funny anymore.

Answer (score 3):

For clarification, I have modified your code to this:

```
Job thread = new Job();
thread.start();
final Object lock = new Object();
synchronized (lock) { lock.wait(); }
System.out.println(thread.getNumber());
```

Now it blocks. That's a first-hand confirmation of what @Nitram has explained in his answer. If you [care to have a look](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/Thread.java#1159) at the `Thread` implementation code, it will be quite obvious why this is the observed behavior.

Comment: So that is equivalent to a `notify`?But `Job` did not held any locks

Comment: `While you are waiting, the lock on that monitor is realeased, anyway` I don't understand what you mean here

Comment: Right.Because `main` is blocked (goes in WAITING state).So how does main get unblocked?

Comment: @Marko: You seem to confuse the actual Operating System Thread and the "Control Object" `java.lang.Thread`. These are only loosly coupled. When the OS-thread terminates, locks and monitors of the Control Object are not touched. Merely some internal flags are changed.

Comment: I don't see that this answers the question. Why does the first thread return from `wait` when the second thread terminates?

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik: Yes, but where does `Job` hold any locks? Not in the visible code.

Comment: _"That's a first-hand confirmation"_ - the OP confirmed it in the first place. The question is _"why"_, and is still unanswered.

Comment: @npe [Here is as to the "why"](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/Thread.java#1159).

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik: But `join` is also not called in the example.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik, no, it's not. It only shows, that the `join()` is implemented using this approach. Why it works, and what are the internal mechanisms of this remains a mystery (at least for me).

Comment: @artbristol The Java source code I have linked to **is** Java.

Comment: @npe And how do you imagine that `join` implementation to work, if not by some code, somewhere, `notify`ing the `Thread` instance?

Comment: @artbristol Have I pasted HotSpot source code? You are confusing OpenJDK with HotSpot, I believe.

Comment: @Marko sorry you're correct. However there are other JDK implementations such as IBM's. So it's still implementation-specific.

Comment: @artbristol That's a better argument. However, just have a look at Peter Lawrey's answer. Turns out it finally [made it into spec](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#join(long)), even though it's been the same since Java 1.0.

Answer (score 3):

**NOTE:** This answer has been edited extensively.

---

The reason for this behaviour is, that "someone" is calling `notifyAll` internally. This "someone" is the JVM itself as you can "see" in the C sources here:

http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/hotspot/hotspot/file/f95d63e2154a/src/share/vm/runtime/thread.cpp

In line 1531 the method `ensure_join` calls `notifyAll`. This is the counterpart to the `wait` calls in `java.lang.Thread#join` (as noted by Marko and others).

`ensure_join` in turn is called in line 1664 in the method `JavaThread::exit`.

---

Since this is "internal bookkeeping" nobody should rely on this behaviour.

Comment: This is an example of what the Java implementors learned from experience to be bad design---using monitors of publicly accessible objects for internal purposes. [See also the flip-side of your code paste](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/Thread.java#1159).

Comment: notifyAll is called on the monitor of the threadGroup, not on the thread.

Comment: @tibtof: Right you are. Sorry.

Answer (score 2):

Simply put a `Thread` notifies all waiting threads once the execution of the threads ends. Its not the proposed why to do this, but it works. To synchronize on the end of a thread rather use `Thread.join`.

Comment: `but it works` You mean you don't have a doc for this, but it is something that you have observed as a behavior?

Comment: Yes it works, because the dying thread will release the lock that was applied using `Object.wait`. But wait will also be released in case you use notify. If you want to be sure that you synchronize on the end of a thread you have to use `Thread.join`.

Comment: The question is not about how and whether the lock is released. The question is about how and whether the object will be signalled, causing `wait` to return.

Comment: Nitram, this is not about releasing any locks, as indeed none are held by either thread. This is about [Thread using `this` for its own purposes](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/Thread.java#1159), which is really a design fail.

Answer (score 0):

A thread object is automatically notified when the thread finishes, that's why the main thread doesn't get stuck.

Comment: Any source to back this? I haven't found anything on this in Javadocs.

Answer (score -1):

Well....notify serves purpose of premature notifying to the threads waiting on the locked object. if you don't use Notify ,then certainly when it finishes it releases lock.

```
So that is equivalent to notify
```

no it's not..Consider the situation below.

```
class Job extends Thread {  
    private Integer number = 0;  
    public void run() {

       synchronized(this) {
       for (int i = 1; i < 1000000; i++) {  
            number++;  
        }  
        notify();     //releases lock here and your main thread continues
        do sumthing...
        do sumthing...
        }  
    }
    public Integer getNumber() {  
        return number;  
    }  
}
```

if you don't use notify() ...lock will be released only after you do all your sumthings..

Comment: Huh?! [notify](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#notify%28%29) doesn't release any locks.

Comment: Your code will throw an exception at runtime as you are calling a `notify` without owning a lock