# Issuing notify on a single thread awakens all waiting threads

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

Having three threads waiting on a 4th one, and the latter issuing a notify, all of the waiting threads are awakened.

Here is the source code:

```
class Reader extends Thread {

  Calculator calc;

  public Reader(Calculator calc) {
    this.calc = calc;
  }

  public void run() {
    synchronized(calc) {
      try {
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " waiting for calc");
        calc.wait();
      } catch (InterruptedException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
      System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " Total is: " + calc.total);
    }   
  }

}

class Calculator extends Thread {

  public int total = 0;

  public void run() {
    synchronized(this) {
      for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
        total += i;
      }
      notify();
      System.out.println("I notified a thread");
    }
  }

}

public class Notify {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Calculator calc = new Calculator();
    Reader r1 = new Reader(calc);
    Reader r2 = new Reader(calc);
    Reader r3 = new Reader(calc);
    r1.start();
    r2.start();
    r3.start();
    calc.start();
  }
}
```

Here is the output I get:

```
Thread-2 waiting for calc
Thread-4 waiting for calc
Thread-3 waiting for calc
I notified a thread
Thread-2 Total is: 1225
Thread-3 Total is: 1225
Thread-4 Total is: 1225
```

Shouldn't only one waiting thread be awakened and execute the `System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " Total is: " + calc.total);` instruction ?

Answer (score 3):

You can't use `wait`/`notify` this way. You have to use `wait` to wait *for something*, something your code can, and must, test. You should only call `notify` after changing something that another thread is actually waiting for such that its test will tell it to no longer wait for it.

> "A thread can also wake up without being notified, interrupted, or timing out, a so-called spurious wakeup. While this will rarely occur in practice, applications must guard against it by testing for the condition that should have caused the thread to be awakened, and continuing to wait if the condition is not satisfied."

In other words, your `wait` logic must look like this:

1. Can I do something now?
2. If no, call `wait` and go to step 1.
3. Do that thing.

And your `notify` logic must look like this:

1. Make it so that another thread can do something.
2. Call `notify`.

These functions are not a generic suspend/resume mechanism. They are specifically a way to synchronize on a predicate managed by code protected by the synchronized block. You can build a suspend/resume mechanism out of them if you want by using your own suspect/resume flag or count if you want to.

Update: Måns Rolandi Danielsson figured out what's going on in your specific case. Your threads are waiting for an object that hasn't launched/terminated already. So when it signals itself that it is ready/finished, the other threads see that signal.

Comment: Actually, after reading your comments I commented the notify() instruction and the waiting threads nevertheless woke up by themselves. So if I understand what you're saying: a thread can wake up by itself even if I didn't explicitly set a timeout for it and that notify hasn't been issued ?

Comment: You may have something else going on as well. While my answer is correct and what you are doing is not supposed to work, it usually "happens to" work. So maybe your threads are getting interrupted or you have some other issue. But still, you should learn how to use notify/wait correctly. (The answer to your question is yes, spurious wakeups are explicitly permitted.)

Comment: And I would advise using higher-level abstractions to do that, like a Semaphore for example.

Comment: David, this is not production code, I'm experimenting with the wait/notify notion. Is it correct if I say - based on the above code and your answer - that wait doesn't guarantee that the waiting thread won't wake up by itself ? Thanks

Comment: That's correct. You have to use `wait` to wait *for something*. You can't use it as a suspend mechanism. (For example: `while (wakecount == 0) wait();` and `wakecount++; notify();`)

Comment: OK. Got that from a book _Sometimes the JVM may call notify() for reasons of its own, or code in some other class calls it for reasons you just don't know_ that's the spurious wakeup you mentioned, hence the mandatory test in addition to wait. Now it's clear to me what made the threads awaken.

Answer (score 3):

I figured out why all the threads awakened even when the calculator thread issued no notify() at all: It's because it finished executing its run() method.

To see the effect of notify() vs notifyAll() I had to keep the calculator running after the call to notify.

So this code:

```
class Calculator extends Thread {

  int total;

  public void run() {
    synchronized(this) {
      for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
        total += i;
      }
      notify();
      System.out.println("I notified a thread");
    }
    try {
     System.out.println("Going to sleep");
     Thread.sleep(5000);
     System.out.println("I finished sleeping");
    } catch(InterruptedException e) {}
  }

}
```

Gives the following output:

```
Thread-2 waiting for calc
Thread-4 waiting for calc
Thread-3 waiting for calc
I notified a thread
Thread-2 Total is: 1225
Going to sleep
I finished sleeping
Thread-3 Total is: 1225
Thread-4 Total is: 1225
```

which shows that only one waiting thread got notified with the notify() call, the two others awakened after the calculator finished its execution.

Replacing notify() with notifyAll() in the previous code gives the following output:

```
Thread-2 waiting for calc
Thread-4 waiting for calc
Thread-3 waiting for calc
I notified all threads
Thread-3 Total is: 1225
Thread-4 Total is: 1225
Thread-2 Total is: 1225
Going to sleep
I finished sleeping
```

Comment: I see what you are getting at, interesting! Anyone can explain this behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

No, because  all Reader objects are given the same Calculator. When the Reader threads starts, the calc.wait() is called *on the same Calculator object*, and then when the Calculator starts and notifies itself, all the Reader threads exits at once. Voilà! **EDIT** Try instead:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException,
  IOException {
  Calculator calc1 = new Calculator();
  Calculator calc2 = new Calculator();
  Calculator calc3 = new Calculator();
  Reader r1 = new Reader(calc1);
  Reader r2 = new Reader(calc2);
  Reader r3 = new Reader(calc3);
  r1.start();
  r2.start();
  r3.start();
  calc2.start();
 }
```

**EDIT2** and if you try this test code below, you can see that r1 and r2, who shares Calculator object, are notified and exit, while r3, who has her own Calculator, keeps waiting:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException,
  IOException {
  Calculator calc1 = new Calculator();
  Calculator calc2 = new Calculator();
  Reader r1 = new Reader(calc1);
  Reader r2 = new Reader(calc1);
  Reader r3 = new Reader(calc2);
  r1.start();
  r2.start();
  r3.start();
  calc1.start();
 }
```

Comment: You are right! That's the explanation for his particular result.

Comment: so where did the -1 come from??

Comment: Someone who doesn't know what they think they know, I imagine.

Comment: No, he's wrong. even without notify or notifyAll the waiting threads get awakened. Moreover, the calculator doesn't notify 'itself', it picks one of the threads waiting on that particular instance to notify it, whereas notifyAll notifies ALL the waiting threads on that instance (see the docs).

Comment: No, he's right. The waiting threads get awakened because they're waiting for an object that becomes ready/finished. The calculator does notify itself because that's how Java threads work. (When you start an object, it becomes ready, and notifies itself so it can begin work.) [See here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11609501/is-a-notify-signalled-on-thread-finish-why-does-this-code-sample-work).

Comment: No he's wrong. It's not because they're waiting on the SAME INSTANCE that they all got wakened by the 'notify' that's in my code. It's because the JVM issued a notifyAll call when the calculator thread started that ALL of the waiting threads awakened.

Comment: Really? In that case, shouldn't all threads in my EDIT2 test code above exit? They don't.

Comment: @jihedamine: They're the same thing. The JVM issued a notifyAll call on the instance that all three are waiting on. Both of these conditions are necessary to explain the observed behavior.

Comment: Each time the notify() is called and the synchronized block exited, another of the waiting objects wakes up, one at a time, seemingly in the same order as they called the wait() method. And when the Calculator instance dies, all remaining wait()-ers are notified. Funny!

Answer (score 0):

I found a line about this behaviour in Exploring Java (Niemeyer):
"For each call to notify(), Java wakes up just one method that is asleep in a wait() call. **If there are multiple threads waiting, Java picks the first thread on a first-in, first-out basis.**"

[Exploring Java](http://oreilly.com/catalog/expjava/excerpt/index.html)

So, using this run() method for the Calculator:

```
public void run() {
    int k = 0;
    while (k++ < 2) {
        synchronized (this) {
            notify();
        }
    }
}
```

will notify the first two waiting instances, one at a time in the order that they  called the wait() method on the calculator instance, and upon exit call notifyAll, which will notify any remaining Reader waiting on this particular instance. This, I believe, is the complete explanation for the behaviour that we have seen in this very interesting discussion.

Answer (score 0):

This mystical behavior has been in Sun's JDK for some years - when a thread terminates, it calls `notifyAll()` on itself.

I didn't known why it does that; but JDK 7 javadoc now explains

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#join%28long%29

> join() uses a loop of this.wait calls conditioned on this.isAlive. As a thread terminates the this.notifyAll method is invoked. It is recommended that applications not use wait, notify, or notifyAll on Thread instances.

so basically, join() is implemented as

```
void join()
    synchronized(this) // this thread object
        while( isAlive() )
            wait();    // depends on a notify when this thread terminates
```

So JDK does that for its own purpose.

The reason is weak though - it'll be better to use another lock to implement join().

But JDK probably can't change the behavior now; there could be some codes that unknowingly/mistakenly depends on this notifyAll() signal; removing it would break these codes.